# Files in public folder do not appear on AWS Amplify hosted React App

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I am working on creating a portfolio website using React and Amplify for hosting. I create the following HTML code

```
      <a
        href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/transcript.pdf'}
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
        className="white-link"
      >
        View my full transcript here.
      </a>
```

and have a file called "transcript.pdf" located in my public folder. If I build and servve the react app locally, this works as intended. However when deployed to Amplify this opens a blank screen instead.

Here is my amplify.yml file which uses npm run build as well.

[image]

What am I missing here? Is this some Amplify specific issue that I have to solve by storing the document in S3?